# Send values from Windows Forms Application to Asp.Net Core Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, api, asp.net-core

I have created a simple Asp.Net Api to show information of students in a Winforms application, however, now I want make an Api that accepts values from a Windows Forms Application and inserts those values to a database. how can I create such thing? here is what I tried so far:

The Asp.Net Api:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class Students : ControllerBase
{
 
     SqlConnection con;
     SqlCommand cmd;

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post()
    {
        string name = "janet";
        string age = "12";
         
        con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into People(name,age) values(@name,@age)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

The Windows Forms Application:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        action();
    }
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    HttpClient client;
    async void action()
    {
            client = new HttpClient();   
  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44338/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            response = await client.GetAsync("api/Students");
            
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("item added successfully");

            }

        }
```

I want to change the name and age variable in the Api to whatever values I enter in the Winforms.

PS:I know that I'm using `client.GetAsync` in the winforms and its supposed to be `client.PostAsync` but I didn't know what parameters I should have passed to it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should read [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) because you're breaking one of the key pieces of guidance there. You might have better experience with [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/), which has a cleaner syntax and takes care of some of those tricky bits for you.

Comment: You should avoid using `async void` except for the event handler itself. Your action method should return a Task, and then button1_Click should await that, and therefore button1_Click must be marked as async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the data in the form of `StringContent` in the second parameter of the **[PostAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=netcore-3.1)** method.

You can put these parameters you need to pass to a model, and convert them to json to the controller.

Here is the demo:

You can create the Person class in these two application(which is convenient to transmit and receive data):

```
 public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
```

The Windows Forms Application:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44338/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
              
               Person  person = new Person() {  name= "janet", age =12};
                var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
                var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                response = await client.PostAsync("api/Students", content);
           

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("item added successfully");

            }

        }
```

Controller api:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]Person person)
        { 
            con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into People(name,age) values(@name,@age)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", person.name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", person.age);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, this finally worked after trying a plethora of links

Comment: You need to read [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) because you're promoting a poor way of using HttpClient. Please update your answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @mason. i will be sure to fix those issues and update my answer